# Write beeline query results to a text file

Tags: hive

I need to write the results of executing a hive query to a file. how do i do it? currently, it's printing to the console.

```
beeline -u db_url -n user_name -p password -f query.sql
```

i tried:

```
beeline -u db_url -n user_name -p password -f query.sql 2> output.txt
```

but output.txt just contains when connection started and closed, not the results of the query - which are still being printed to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `beeline -u db_url -n user_name -p password -f query.sql > output.txt` must be OK. Without `2`

Comment: Prints crappy output. How does one print out tab delimited?

Comment: @Chris https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/05/28/3-ways-to-make-tab-delimited-files-from-your-mysql-table/

Comment: It prints the output but along with hell lot of craps. Below is the o/p that I have got from the file.                                                                                        > 0: jdbc:hive2://10.211.1.5:10000/> use db;
0: jdbc:hive2://10.211.1.5:10000/> select count(*) from sample_table;
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 131  |
+------+--+
0: jdbc:hive2://10.211.1.5:10000/> 
0: jdbc:hive2://10.211.1.5:10000/> 
0: jdbc:hive2://10.211.1.5:10000/>

Answer (score 0):

"2" in your command is errlog, not the stdout
so "...query.sql 2> output.txt" would put the errlog results into your text file, while "...query.sql > output.txt" would put the actual output into the text file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @dds 's answer you can try adding the silent feature to get rid of all the other stuffs like the connection started and closed status being printed in the output file.

```
beeline -u db_url -n user_name -p password --silent=true -f query.sql > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to type "csv2" instead of "csv 2". Here's the fixed command line:

```
beeline -u db_url -n user_name -p password -f query.sql2 > output.txt
```